# PIL shows "broken data stream when reading image file" in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

My python and PIL installation is from MacPorts on Snow Leopard.

When I try to open a JPG image in the system python with PIL, I don't get any errors.

```
$ python
>>> import Image
>>> img = Image.open("test.jpg")
>>> img2 = img.resize((1,1))
>>> # no errors!!!
```

However when I create a virtual environment

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
$ cd venv/
$ source bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install PIL
...
(venv) $ python
>>> import Image
>>> img = Image.open("../test.jpg")
>>> img2 = img.resize((1,1))
...
IOError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

[Here](http://pastebin.com/fyR9b7UC) is a whole dump including the whole build of PIL.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get from


>>> from PIL import _imaging

>>> _imaging

Comment: within virtualenv : `<module 'PIL._imaging' from '/Users/miki725/Development/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so'>`

in the system : `<module 'PIL._imaging' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so'>`

Comment: Seems to work ok for me with python 2.7 and py27-virtualenv 1.6.1. What versions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue.

Generally people should not be using PIL anymore

Give Pillow a try https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

I am willing to bet this plays nice in the venv

Comment: yes. thanks. Pillow is much better. solves a bunch of these errors.